react-native-calendars month , year , dates custom assigning issue
In react-native-calendars, I want to change the month, year, and their respective dates using my custom month and year picklist.
(https://i.sstatic.net/7ouTICxe.png)
I am trying to change / Assign the selected dates useState to the standard react-native-calendar component but it is not working

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

add this to the component where you use the Calendar, with this you can sign the months/days as you like, for example locale on ru


import {Calendar, LocaleConfig} from 'react-native-calendars';

LocaleConfig.locales['rus'] = {
    monthNames: [
        'Январь',
        'Февраль',
        'Март',
        'Апрель',
        'Май',
        'Июнь',
        'Июль',
        'Август',
        'Сентябрь',
        'Октябрь',
        'Ноябрь',
        'Декабрь'
    ],
    monthNamesShort: ['Янв.', 'Фев.', 'Мар.', 'Апр.', 'Май', 'Июнь', 'Июль', 'Авг.', 'Сен.', 'Окт.', 'Ноя.', 'Дек.'],
    dayNames: ['Понедельник', 'Вторник', 'Среда', 'Четверг', 'Пятница', 'Суббота', 'Воскресенье'],
    dayNamesShort: ['Пон.', 'Вт.', 'Ср.', 'Чет.', 'Пят.', 'Суб.', 'Вос.'],
    today: "Сегодня"
};
LocaleConfig.defaultLocale = 'rus';



